# Is my use of "that that" in this sentence gramaticaly correct

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Abbreviated version:
"I thought that that wasn't a thing in the U.S.A. anymore at all!"

Entire sentence:
"My entire world was blown away when I heard that 800,000 kids in America (the U.S.A.) work illegally, because I thought that that wasn't a thing in the U.S.A. anymore at all!"

Comment: Bear in mind that "that" and "that" are two different words with different meanings.  (Or should I have said "Bear in mind that that "that" and the other "that" are two different words"?)

Comment: Oops, misspoke!  Should have been "Bear in mind that that "that" that appears first in your sentence and that "that" that appears second are two different words".

Comment: @HotLicks Well, there is that.

Answer (score 3):

Grammatically it is correct.  The first 'that' would be a conjunction; something like 'I thought that' or 'I feel that'.

The second 'that' would be a pronoun, such as 'that wasn't a thing' or 'that was no longer acceptable'.

Structured together would be:
I thought that that wasn't a thing anymore
I thought that that was no longer acceptable.

If it bothers you, you can usually remove one of the "that's", leaving you with: "because I thought that wasn't a thing in the U.S.A anymore".

Hope this helps!